# Bat file that creates directories with a directory name that takes from a .txt file

Tags: batch-file

I have to make a BAT file that makes directories with a name thats taken from a .txt file, also this names have to be only the two first characters from the tokens. To clarify, heres is the .txt content that the for command has to take:

```
Jose;Leon;70234567
Ana;Sierra;20001110
```

And i have to create directories with names that look like this:

```
JoLeo67
AnSie10
```

(First two characters from the first token, first three characters from second token and first 2 digits from the third token)

I have this for command made so far:

```
for /f "TOKENS=1,2,3 DELIMS=;" %i in (C:\Users\usuario\MisDOC\fichero.txt) do 
( SET nom=%i && SET ape=%j && SET dni=%k  ) && 
(md C:\Users\usuario\%nom:~,2%%ape:~,3%%dni:~,2%)
```

The issue is that it creates both directories with the same name.  Heres the cmd output:

[image: CMD Output]

tested with echo instead of md for convenienceI understand that inside the BATCH file variables have to be named with two %%

Heres a screenshot with the actual content in the batch file:
[image: BATCH file]

Anyone can help? Sorry if its not clear enough, english is not my first language. Thanks in advance

tested with echo instead of md for convenience

(tested with echo instead of md for convenience)

Comment: Either `EnableDelayedExpansion` or use a pseudo `Call`.

Comment: Why are you using &&?

Answer (score 0):

You ought to use [DelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). Just create such a bat-file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "TOKENS=1,2,3 DELIMS=;" %%i in (C:\Users\usuario\MisDOC\fichero.txt) do ( SET nom=%%i && SET ape=%%j && SET dni=%%k ) && (md C:\Users\usuario\!nom:~,2!!ape:~,3!!dni:~-3!)
```